# How would you improve the performance of this function?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, distance

```
import numpy

def euclideanClassification(punto1, punto2):
    return (numpy.dot(punto2, punto1) - ((1.0/2.0) * numpy.dot(punto1, punto1)))
```

I'm trying to improve the performance of this function, but I don't know how.

This function is a variant of the Euclidean distance used in pattern recognition.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `punto1` and `punto2`?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, that formula should be equivalent to this:

```
numpy.dot(punto2 - 0.5 * punto1, punto1)
```

but if you write it like this you save three multiplications, so in theory it should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cython](http://cython.org/) for that task.

> [Cython] is a programming language based on Python, with extra syntax allowing for optional static type declarations. It aims to become a superset of the [Python] language which gives it high-level, object-oriented, functional, and dynamic programming. The source code gets translated into optimized C/C++ code and compiled as Python extension modules. This allows for both very fast program execution and tight integration with external C libraries, while keeping up the high programmer productivity for which the Python language is well known.